# How to log in thru webservices

Tags: jspresso

From an external application, I am calling a rest web service that is implemented in Jspresso.

In the Jspresso web service, I would like to initialize the environment/context in order to act like a user connected by the login module.

Is there a method to call to initialize the environment (userPrincipal, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, your web services classes should extend `org.jspresso.framework.application.startup.AbstractBackendStartup`.
Then you can use the following protected methods :

- `protected Subject createSubject(String userName)`
- `protected void configureApplicationSession(Subject subject, Locale locale)`

This will initialize a session with all necessary information.